# Exponential Confidence Interval

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

It is known that, for large $n$:

$$\sqrt{n}(\lambda\bar{x}-1) \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$$

With this approximation, show that the 95% confidence interval for $\lambda$ is:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n} - 1.96}{\sqrt{n}\bar{x}}, \quad \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1.96}{\sqrt{n}\bar{x}}$$

I think I need to manipulate the formula for confidence intervals for exponential distributions but I'm not sure where to start (simplified version since large $n$?)

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem will give you this if you can calculate the relevant mean and variance.

Comment: Development of question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019054/central-limit-theorem-for-exponential-distribution

Answer (score 2):

About $95\%$ of the probability distribution of a standard normal distribution lies in the interval $(-1.96,1.96)$.

So all you need to do is manipulate  $$P\left(-1.96 \lt \sqrt{n}(\lambda\bar{x}-1) \lt 1.96 \right)=0.95$$ to something like $$P\left(\frac{\sqrt{n} - 1.96}{\sqrt{n}\bar{x}} \lt \lambda \lt \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1.96}{\sqrt{n}\bar{x}} \right)=0.95$$ remembering that $\bar{x}$ is a random variable while $\lambda$ is not.

Comment: I just don't see where the $\sqrt{n}$ comes from on the top?

Comment: I've gotten to $\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}\bar{x}}$ and I'm left with $\lambda - 1$ in the middle

Comment: You start with $\sqrt{n}(\lambda\bar{x}-1)$ in the middle.  What is on the outside? Then you have $\lambda\bar{x}-1$ in the middle.  What is on the outside?  Then you have $\lambda\bar{x}$ in the middle.  What is on the outside? Then you have $\lambda$ in the middle.  What is on the outside?